# mySQL 5.7 not working correctly with groups

Tags: php, mysql

I have upgraded my datababase to mysql 5.7.15, and I keep getting this error message everytime I try to run the following query

```
SELECT `hired_proj_id` 
FROM `hired_projects` 
WHERE `status_code` = '3' 
  AND `client_id` = 55 
GROUP BY `proj_id` 
ORDER BY `hired_proj_id` DESC;
```

Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'sandbox.hired_projects.hired_proj_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I have been look through stackover flow, but was unable to find an answer. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Please supply your table definition and some sample data

Comment: Please provide information on your database structure. I.e. list a few lines of "create table ..." and maybe some sample input by listing some lines of "insert ...", i.e. try to get as close as possible to a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned yesterday this thanks to Gordon Linoff

> All columns in the select should either be columns in the group by or
>   use aggregate functions (sum(), avg(), and so on).

Your query:

```
  SELECT `hired_proj_id` 
    FROM `hired_projects` 
   WHERE `status_code` = '3' 
     AND `client_id` = 55 
GROUP BY `proj_id` 
ORDER BY `hired_proj_id` DESC
```

When we check your query we see that the selected `'hired_proj_id'` is not in your `GROUP BY`.

Your query should be like this:

```
    SELECT `hired_proj_id` 
      FROM `hired_projects` 
     WHERE `status_code` = '3' 
       AND `client_id` = 55 
  GROUP BY `hired_proj_id`,`proj_id` 
  ORDER BY `hired_proj_id` DESC
```

This is probably your solution.

Comment: Or, use an aggregate function on it.

Comment: @Don'tPanic yup, your correct but my suggestion is only to help him to the right direction. Since the answer is also quoted that is why I did not used the aggregate function.

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of hard to know which one would be better when they haven't really described what it's supposed to do.

Comment: And the hardest thing is when you comment or suggest something and you wait for the user's reply, and he doesn't answer!

Comment: @MrProPop it is always taking / giving in this situation he gets nothing if he do not provide us more information.

Comment: Yes, I understand and I am friendly, but just got bored from waiting haha long time to reply and it is 3:15 AM waiting to see if he still needs help!

Answer (score 0):

> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

the error is clear, either you add the field on the `SELECT` to the `GROUP BY`

```
   SELECT <fieldName>
   FROM yourTable
   WHERE <conditions>
   GROUP BY <fieldName>
```

OR add an aggregated function on the `SELECT`

```
   SELECT SUM(<fieldName>)
   FROM yourTable
   WHERE <conditions>
   GROUP BY <otherfieldName>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note: MySQL is insecure and is deprecated, use PDO or MySQLi instead.**

Here is an implementation with MySQLi,

```
 <?php

     //MySQLi information

        $db_host     = "localhost";
        $db_username = "username";
        $db_password = "password";

        //connect to mysqli database (Host/Username/Password)
        $connection = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die("Error " . mysqli_error());

        //select MySQLi dabatase table
        $db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "table") or die("Error " . mysqli_error());

  $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "

    SELECT `hired_proj_id` 
      FROM `hired_projects` 
     WHERE `status_code` = '3' 
       AND `client_id` = 55 
  GROUP BY `hired_proj_id`,`proj_id` 
  ORDER BY `hired_proj_id` DESC

");

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the query you really want is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT hired_proj_id 
FROM hired_projects
WHERE status_code = 3 AND client_id = 55 
ORDER BY hired_proj_id DESC;
```

Notes:

- Don't enclose numeric constants in single quotes -- unless they are really strings.
- No need to use backticks everywhere.